# Trying to display images instead of letters for Rock Paper Scissors game

Tags: javascript

I am working on a R,P,S game and I want to display images instead of letters for the choices the user and computer make. I started an if statement about half way down the page but I cant seem to get it to display the image on the page. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
                var computerChoices = ['r', 'p', 's'];
                var wins = 0;
                var losses = 0;
                var ties = 0;

                document.onkeyup = function(event) {
                    var userGuess = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();
                    var computerGuess = computerChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerChoices.length)];

                    if ((userGuess == 'r') || (userGuess == 'p') || (userGuess == 's')){

                        if ((userGuess == 'r') && (computerGuess == 's')){
                            wins++;
                        }else if ((userGuess == 'r') && (computerGuess == 'p')){
                            losses++;
                        }else if ((userGuess == 's') && (computerGuess == 'r')){
                            losses++;
                        }else if ((userGuess == 's') && (computerGuess == 'p')){
                            wins++;
                        }else if ((userGuess == 'p') && (computerGuess == 'r')){
                            wins++;
                        }else if ((userGuess == 'p') && (computerGuess == 's')){
                            losses++;
                        }else if (userGuess == computerGuess){
                            ties++;
                        } 

                        if (userGuess == 'r'){
                            var displayRock = "<img src='images/rock-user.png' alt='User Rock'>";
                            document.querySelector("#userGuess").innerHTML = displayRock;
                        }

                        var displayWins = wins;
                        document.querySelector('#wins').innerHTML = displayWins;

                        var displayLosses = losses;
                        document.querySelector('#losses').innerHTML = displayLosses;

                        var displayTies = ties;
                        document.querySelector('#ties').innerHTML = displayTies;

                        var displayUserGuess = userGuess;
                        document.querySelector('#userGuess').innerHTML = displayUserGuess;

                        var displayComputerGuess = computerGuess;
                        document.querySelector('#computerGuess').innerHTML = displayComputerGuess;

                        document.querySelector('#game').innerHTML = html;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: If you're using Chrome, open the developer tools and inspect the HTML where this image is supposed to be inserted. Check the console for log errors, and check the network tab for errors relating to finding your picture file.

Comment: Since you only will have one of three images, why not preload them and just show/hide them as needed `display:[none][block]`.  Another option is to have an `img` element already there and simply manipulate the`src`  ie `document.getElementById('myImage').setAttribute('src',imagepath)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the image:

```
if (userGuess == 'r'){
    var displayRock = "<img src='images/rock-user.png' alt='User Rock'>";
    document.querySelector("#userGuess").innerHTML = displayRock;
}
```

And it is immediatelly being replaced a few lines below:

```
document.querySelector('#userGuess').innerHTML = displayUserGuess;
```

You might want to use the [insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', displayUserGuess)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) function.

Also, it is not good practice to query for the same element multiple times - it is better to query once and keep it in a variable like:

```
var userGuessEl = document.querySelector('#userGuess');

// and then below
userGuessEl.innerHTML = ...
```